# Creating a dictionary out of a CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file with zip codes and their timezones. How do I convert the CSV file to a dictionary? This will be a module for a bigger assignment. My code looks like this and I'm stuck on what to do next:

```
import csv

with open('zipcode.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row

input_file = csv.DictReader(open("zipcode.csv"))
```

Comment: DictReader is designed to turn each row of the csv file into a separate dictionary.  Is that what you want?  if not, the other option is to have a particular field in the data act as the dictionary key.  If you wanted to do that, you should create a dictionary with `my_dict = {}` before you open the file, and then replace `print row` with `my_dict[row[0]] = row[1]` or something similar.

Comment: I want each zip code to be a key while the time zone is a value. Zip codes are unique while the timezones can repeat. The whole assignment is to match a client's zip code to their time zone so they can be put in order of who to contact first by phone number.

Comment: In that case the second approach I outlined is the correct one.  Take each line from the csv and add it to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Making a guess at your file structure, try this:

```
import csv

my_dict = {}

with open('zipcode.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        my_dict[row[0]] = row[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your data file looks like, but here is a way to do it using pandas DataFrame, assuming your csv file has two columns: zip_code and time_zone, separated by comma, without any headers:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('zipdata.csv', header=None) 
my_dict = dict(zip(df[0], df[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple script should help you figure it out. You won't need to use `DictReader`.

## test.py

```
import csv

# Open the file
with open('zipdata.csv') as f:
  # Populate a dictionary with the reader
  my_dict = dict(csv.reader(f))

# Print the key-value pairs
for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
  print("{}: {}".format(k, v))
```

I used my own test csv file, `test.csv` and here's the output:

```
23:59 $ cat test.csv
hello, world
test, testing
✔ ~ 
23:59 $ python test.py 
test:  testing
hello:  world
```